# C++ expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token & expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile RetroArch in windows with gcc but at the compilation process there's an error:

```
In file included from gfx/drivers/d3d10.c:39:
gfx/drivers/../common/d3d10_common.h:1121:8: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 1121 |        (!(sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) & 0xF)), "sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) must be a multiple of 16");
      |        ^
gfx/drivers/../common/d3d10_common.h:1121:44: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
 1121 |        (!(sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) & 0xF)), "sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) must be a multiple of 16");
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from gfx/common/d3d10_common.c:20:
gfx/common/d3d10_common.h:1121:8: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 1121 |        (!(sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) & 0xF)), "sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) must be a multiple of 16");
      |        ^
gfx/common/d3d10_common.h:1121:44: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
 1121 |        (!(sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) & 0xF)), "sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) must be a multiple of 16");
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:213: obj-unix/release/gfx/drivers/d3d10.o] Error 1
make: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
make: *** [Makefile:213: obj-unix/release/gfx/common/d3d10_common.o] Error 1
In file included from gfx/drivers_font/d3d10_font.c:26:
gfx/drivers_font/../common/d3d10_common.h:1121:8: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 1121 |        (!(sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) & 0xF)), "sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) must be a multiple of 16");
      |        ^
gfx/drivers_font/../common/d3d10_common.h:1121:44: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
 1121 |        (!(sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) & 0xF)), "sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) must be a multiple of 16");
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:213: obj-unix/release/gfx/drivers_font/d3d10_font.o] Error 1
In file included from menu/drivers_display/menu_display_d3d10.c:29:
/home/<user>/retroarch/gfx/common/d3d10_common.h:1121:8: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 1121 |        (!(sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) & 0xF)), "sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) must be a multiple of 16");
      |        ^
/home/<user>/retroarch/gfx/common/d3d10_common.h:1121:44: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
 1121 |        (!(sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) & 0xF)), "sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) must be a multiple of 16");
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:213: obj-unix/release/menu/drivers_display/menu_display_d3d10.o] Error 1
```

I'm an initiated in c++ and I don't know how to fix it, I've tried to add the ‘ & ’ signs before and after the statement but it gives me another error.
Here's the code which gives me the error:

```
(!(sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) & 0xF)), "sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) must be a multiple of 16");
```

Surrounding code:

```
#ifndef ALIGN
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define ALIGN(x) __declspec(align(x))
#else
#define ALIGN(x) __attribute__((aligned(x)))
#endif
#endif

typedef struct ALIGN(16)
{
   math_matrix_4x4 mvp;
   struct
   {
      float width;
      float height;
   } OutputSize;
   float time;
} d3d10_uniform_t;

static_assert(
       (!(sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) & 0xF)), "sizeof(d3d10_uniform_t) must be a multiple of 16");

typedef struct d3d10_shader_t
{
   D3D10VertexShader   vs;
   D3D10PixelShader    ps;
   D3D10GeometryShader gs;
   D3D10InputLayout    layout;
} d3d10_shader_t;

typedef struct
{
   unsigned              cur_mon_id;
   DXGISwapChain         swapChain;
   D3D10Device           device;
   D3D10RasterizerState  state;
   D3D10RenderTargetView renderTargetView;
   D3D10Buffer           ubo;
   d3d10_uniform_t       ubo_values;
   D3D10SamplerState     samplers[RARCH_FILTER_MAX][RARCH_WRAP_MAX];
   D3D10BlendState       blend_enable;
   D3D10BlendState       blend_disable;
   D3D10BlendState       blend_pipeline;
   D3D10Buffer           menu_pipeline_vbo;
   math_matrix_4x4       mvp, mvp_no_rot;
   struct video_viewport vp;
   D3D10_VIEWPORT        viewport;
   DXGI_FORMAT           format;
   float                 clearcolor[4];
   bool                  vsync;
   bool                  resize_chain;
   bool                  keep_aspect;
   bool                  resize_viewport;
   bool                  resize_render_targets;
   bool                  init_history;
   d3d10_shader_t        shaders[GFX_MAX_SHADERS];
#ifdef __WINRT__
   DXGIFactory2 factory;
#else
   DXGIFactory factory;
#endif
   DXGIAdapter adapter;
```

File download:
https://mega.nz/#!5vxUkYYS!jolCYJd_qwxxdZ5F0jFCaG-l2an-iX5pd0LnhCAlNXo

How can I fix it?

Comment: The problematic part is most likely before this line. In fact, the one code line you show has mismatched parentheses so there's definitely stuff missing. Can you provide more lines of surrounding code?

Comment: @MaxLanghof  : Done. And added download link.

Comment: @JeffLee Download links should **never** be a part of the question. That's why [mre], inside a question itself, is a **requirement**.

Comment: How are you compiling this program? What version of gcc? (The line does trigger an error under C++03, but it seems to work under C++11, when `static_assert` was introduced.)

Comment: @JaMiT : ```$ gcc --version /
gcc (GCC) 9.1.0 /
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.``` I'm using MSYS2 I downloaded gcc from pacman

Comment: What compiler options are you using?

Comment: Well... I downloaded make from pacman and the command is: ```make -j4``` You can look at what I've done here: https://docs.libretro.com/development/retroarch/compilation/windows/

Comment: That version of gcc is new enough to use C++11 by default. That leaves... not sure. It might be up to you to trim the code down to a [mcve], as I was not able to reproduce the error using the code currently in the question. It's possible someone will have the time to dig through your linked code, but I would not count on it.